# Custom listView repeating values and changing them on scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have made a listview with a custom adapter. There are five textviews, 1 checkbox and one button.

```
-------------------------------------
    <TextView>  
    <TextView>   <checkbox>
    <TextView>  
    <TextView>    <button>
    <TextView>  
-------------------------------------
```

The arraylists that I am using to populate the textviews in the list has proper unique data. But the listview takes only four to five values of the begining and repeates it in the rest of the list.

Also when I scroll the values displayed change automatically. For example item A was displayed at first position. So when I scroll down and then come up again, item C or item D is displayed.

It is really confusing me! Please help!

**Custom Adapter code**

```
protected class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    int len;
    private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    private SparseBooleanArray favourites;

    ArrayList<String> myMake, myModel, myVer, myPrice, myPlace, sellr_pos;
    int count = 0;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Boolean status;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,

    ArrayList<String> car_make, ArrayList<String> car_model,
            ArrayList<String> car_version, ArrayList<String> car_price,
            ArrayList<String> car_place, ArrayList<String> sellr_pos) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(car_model.size());
        favourites = new SparseBooleanArray(car_model.size());

        myMake = car_make;
        myModel = car_model;
        myVer = car_version;
        myPrice = car_price;
        myPlace = car_place;

    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5;
        CheckBox chkbox;
        Button btn_fav;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myMake.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.text_adaptr, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text5);
            holder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            holder.txt4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text4);
            holder.txt5 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

            System.out.println("ListView position: " + position);

            holder.txt1.setText(myMake.get(position));
            holder.txt2.setText(myModel.get(position));
            holder.txt3.setText(myVer.get(position));
            holder.txt4.setText(myPrice.get(position));
            holder.txt5.setText(myPlace.get(position));

            holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.btn_fav = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.chkbox.setTag(position);

        holder.chkbox.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));

        if (favourites.get(position, false)) {

            holder.btn_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);


        } else {
            holder.btn_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_grey);

        }

        len = fav_ids.size();

        System.out.println("FAV_IDS len:" + len);

        for (int t = 0; t < len; t++) {

            String pos_id = pos.get(position).trim();
            String fav_id = fav_ids.get(t).trim();

            if (pos_id.equals(fav_id)) {


                holder.btn_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star);

                break;

            } else {

                holder.btn_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_grey);
            }

        }

        holder.chkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            // Do something

            }
        });

        holder.btn_fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Do something

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not making an Adapter of a custom POJO class, something like class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CarInfo>, where CarInfo would be a class holding String objects (model, version, price, etc) ? It would simplify your code, and you wouldn't even need to take 6 ArrayList<String> in your constructor. Just a design suggestion ;-)

Comment: yes you are right! But it has already got too big and complex now.. and I have got very less time.. but I will surely try to refine it later

Answer (score 3):

Set Values to the TextView at

```
if (convertView == null) {
....code...
........../.

/*
you are setting values here
remove it from here
*/
 holder.txt1.setText(myMake.get(position));
            holder.txt2.setText(myModel.get(position));
            holder.txt3.setText(myVer.get(position));
            holder.txt4.setText(myPrice.get(position));
            holder.txt5.setText(myPlace.get(position));
}
else
{
....code...
}


/*
Set values here
it will solve the problem
*/
holder.txt1.setText(myMake.get(position));
            holder.txt2.setText(myModel.get(position));
            holder.txt3.setText(myVer.get(position));
            holder.txt4.setText(myPrice.get(position));
            holder.txt5.setText(myPlace.get(position));
```

It solves  my problem